# How to scroll div in iframe to an anchor from another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, anchor

Don't know if title makes sense to you, let me expand:

I have a base html file, that contains, among other things `iframe1`. `iframe1` contains 6 links that should link to anchors in a `div` in `iframe2`; and `iframe2` is loaded in place of `iframe1` with `target="_self"`. Now, the trick is, that it should scroll the `div`, not the `iframe2` itself, as there are other things in `iframe2` that should stay in view.

A lot of searching didn't get me anywhere, so I don't even know if this is possible, so I thought I'll give it a try here, before being forced to rework this entire convoluted structure to something else. I'm new to javascript, but I know what a function or variable is :) Thanks.

So, in the master html I have:

```
<div class="content">    
<iframe class="iframes" src="iframes/i-servlinks.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

In iframe1 (called `i-servlinks.html` here) I have 6 of these:

```
<div class="works">
<a class="worklinks" href="i-servs.html" target="_self">Linktoanchor</a>
</div>
```

And in iframe2 (called `i-serv.html` here) I have:

```
<div class="servlinks">
<a class="tab-item" href="#link1">1</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#link2">2</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#link3">3</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#link4">4</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#link5">5</a>
<a class="tab-item" href="#link6">6</a>
</div>
<div class="servs">
<!-- a lot of text, with the 6 anchors spread out in it, and this is the div that should scroll, servlinks div should stay in view on top of iframe2 -->
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you think it might be possible for you to post a MWE (Minimal Working Example) inside your question. That would probably help to clarify the issue faster. Code formats by clicking **{}** after highlighting text, or by putting the code in between backticks → **`** ←.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I gave up, after trying a thousand scrollTo type plugins and scripts, it just wouldn't work right in my setup. So, instead I moved the contents of `iframe1` and `iframe2` into my main `html`, and put `iframe1` into a `div`  that keeps the content of `iframe2` just outside the main `container`, until  I hide it with any of the 6 links `onclick` (with like two lines of `javascript`). I reworked my `html` and `css` a little, and BANG, it works like a charm.

Same functionality, but actually much cleaner, less files and less scripts. So this just goes to demonstrate that thinking simpler is usually better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use some Javascript to override the default scroll behaviour. I have create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpL1mvvc/) to illustrate.

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this=$(this);
  var id = $this.attr('href');
  var offset = $(id)[0].offsetTop;
  var wrapY=$('.wrap')[0].offsetTop;
  $('.wrap').scrollTop(offset-wrapY);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure, where am I supposed to add this code in my setup? Within `iframe2` scrolling works just fine, my problem is that I can't get the `div` in it to jump to a specific anchor when I click a link in `iframe1`